# Where is the window size in Pytorch LSTM model incorporated?

Tags: pytorch, lstm

I have built a lstm model that takes input data with 3 features and the rolling window size is 18. My model has layers as I have attached in the code below. What I don't understand is how is the rolling window size of 18 incorporated in the model if the window size is never passed as an argument to the model. And if the model takes input as just one row at a time, is it not equivalent to using window size = 1?

```
class LSTMnetwork(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,input_size=3,hidden_size1=24, hidden_size2=50, hidden_size3=20,output_size=1):
    super().__init__()
    self.hidden_size1 = hidden_size1
    self.hidden_size2 = hidden_size2
    self.hidden_size3 = hidden_size3
    
    # Add an LSTM and dropout layer:
    self.lstm1 = nn.LSTM(input_size,hidden_size1)
    self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
    
    # Add second LSTM and dropout layer:
    self.lstm2 = nn.LSTM(hidden_size1,hidden_size2)
    self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
    
    # Add a fully-connected layer:
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_size2,hidden_size3)
    
    # Add a fully-connected layer:
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size3,output_size)
    
    # Initialize h0 and c0:
    self.hidden1 = (torch.zeros(1,1,self.hidden_size1),
                   torch.zeros(1,1,self.hidden_size1))
    
    # Initialize h1 and c1:
    self.hidden2 = (torch.zeros(1,1,self.hidden_size2),
                   torch.zeros(1,1,self.hidden_size2))

def forward(self,seq):
    lstm1_out, self.hidden1 = self.lstm1(seq.view(len(seq),1,-1), self.hidden1)
    dropout1 = self.dropout1(lstm1_out)
    lstm2_out, self.hidden2 = self.lstm2(dropout1.view(len(dropout1),1,-1), self.hidden2)
    dropout2 = self.dropout2(lstm2_out)
    fc1_out = F.relu(self.fc1(dropout2))
    fc2_out = self.fc2(fc1_out)
    return fc2_out[-1]
```